# Example of a non-Galois extension with $[L : K] = |Aut(L/K)|$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

When an extension of fields $L/K$ is finite, we always have $|\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)| \leq [L : K]$, and if $L/K$ is Galois then $|\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)| = [L : K]$.  Is the converse true?

Is there an example of an infinite extension $L/K$ with $|\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)| > [L : K]$?

Comment: yes the converse is true.

Comment: You're right, and that's obvious too.  I don't know why I didn't realize that.  If $K_0 \supsetneq K$ is the fixed fixed of $Aut(L/K) = Aut(L/K_0)$, then $|Aut(L/K)| = |Aut(L/K_0)| = [L : K_0] < [L : K]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addresses your second question.

Take $K$ to be the field with a prime number $p$ of elements, and $L$ its algebraic closure.

Then $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is uncontable (it is isomorphic to the profinite closure of the integers).

However, the degree of $L$ over $K$ is countable, as $L$ is the union (direct limit) of all fields of order $p^{n}$, for $n$ in the positive integers. (Actually, $L$ itself is countable.)